# Polymorphic relationships in Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, polymorphic-associations

With Parse.com is it possible to use the Array type to save polymorphic relationships within a class?

An example would be something like having tasks being grouped into a containing "package". These packages can contain references to one or more tasks as well as references to other packages. It seems that using the Array type like this ***should*** be possible with something like the following json string stored in the array:

```
[
    { "__type": "Pointer", "className": "Task", "objectId": "AhuYAHlAbw" },
    { "__type": "Pointer", "className": "Package", "objectId": "uNFic6Sb48" }
]
```

Has anyone tried this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that works perfectly fine. You would just need to test for the kind of class whenever using the members of the array (using PFObject.className, not isKindOfClass).

Comment: Good deal. Figured it would work but I saw nothing in the documentation on using arrays in that manner. Thanks!

Comment: True, I never saw it either. But I have tested it, and it works.

Comment: so I'm just getting around to working on the code for this - how in the world do you query an array of Pointers for a className and objectId? I'm using the Javascript SDK.

Comment: So I sort of have it working. I query all of the parent objects then loop through them getting each array property and check that the type and id of array[0] matches what I'm after. Works fine with 3 parentObjects. Will suck immensely once data gets moving. Hoping there's a better way!

Comment: meant to mention you in these comments.

Comment: Good question. In my usecase, I never query them. I'm always interested in ALL members. What exactly is your usecase?

Comment: I have a class called `Effectivity` that determines what products my `Tasks` apply to. `Packages` should inherit all `Effectivity` from their child `Tasks` but also can limit the `Effectivity` to a subset of the inherited `Effectivity`. In my `Effectivity` class there is a column called `effectiveTo` that is an array similar to my OP that will always contain an array with 1 member. I need to be able to query `effectiveTo` by the `className` and/or the `objectId` in the array.